# Value: I/O operation on closed file

Tags: python, file, function, file-io

**trying to fix this error but could not any help is appreciated new bie python looked up in other questions too but could not fix it** code snippet works separately but as a whole does not seem to work could not figure out what is wrong
**error**

```
**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "view_log_info.sh", line 139, in <module>
    print network_adapter
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file**

#!usr/bin/env/ python
import sys, re, os, getpass

#function to find the packetloss data in pcoip server files
def function_pcoip_packetloss(filename):
        lineContains = re.compile('.*Loss=.*')  #look for "Loss=" in the file
        for line in filename:
                if lineContains.match(line):    #check if line matches "Loss="
                        print 'The file has: '  #prints if "Loss=" is found
                        print line
                        return 0;
#function to find the decrease in pcoip_server files
def function_pcoip_decrease(filename):
        lineContainsDecrease = re.compile('.*Decrease.*')
        for line in filename:
                if lineContainsDecrease.match(line):    #check if line matches "Decrease"
                        print 'The file has: '          #prints if "Decrease is found"
                        print line
                        return 0;
#function to find the disconnect codes in pcoip_server_files
def function_disconnect_codes(filename):
        lineContains_disconnectCode = re.compile(r'(?=.*disconnect cause)')
        lineContains_Code = re.compile(r'cause\s*\(.*?(\d+)\)')

        for line in filename:
                if lineContains_disconnectCode.match(line):
                        print 'The file has: '
                        print line
                        code = lineContains_Code.search(line).group(1)
                        print 'The code is:', code
                        if code == '000':
                                print 'PCoIP session terminated due to lost network.'
                        elif code == '100':
                                print 'PCoIP connection not established due to failure of PCoIP server initialization. This should not occur. Please contact Teradici support.'
                        elif code == '101':
                                print 'PCoIP connection not established due to failure of PCoIP server initialization. This should not occur in normal operation. Note: If the Welcome Screen is enable in the View Administrator a ConnectionTicketTimeout will trigger a disconnect after 15 min with this code'
                        elif code == '102':
                                print 'PCoIP session terminated due to VMware View Connection Server (broker) maximum session duration (Connection Server setting) exceeded.'
                        elif code == '103':
                                print 'PCoIP session terminated due to the VDI user selecting Logoff or Restart from Windows in the VDI session'            
                        elif code == '104':
                                print 'PCoIP session terminated due to admin manually disconnected the session from the Administrative Web Interface.'
                        elif code == '105':
                                print 'PCoIP session terminated due to login from an alternate location' 
                                print 'OR Pre-connection warmup initialization of PCoIP Server. This is not for actual connection. If the size of the log is under 15 Kbytes, this is a pre-connection warmup startup/shutdown sequence.'
                        elif code == '200':
                                print 'PCoIP session terminated due to the user right-clicking the host driver icon in the tray and then selecting Menu > Disconnect. Applicable only to clients connecting to a hard host and not VDI.'
                        elif code == '201':
                                print 'PCoIP connection not established due to incompatible host driver version (not used for VDI).'
                        elif code == '300':
                                print 'PCoIP session terminated due to the user closing the View Client window or due to the user ending the View application task inside the Windows Task Manager'
                        elif code == '301':
                                print 'PCoIP session terminated due to the user clicking the zero clients Disconnect button. Not applicable for soft clients.'
                        elif code == '302':
                                print 'PCoIP session terminated due to the user clicking the Disconnect button in the client Administrative Web Interface. Not applicable for soft clients.'
                        elif code == '303':
                                print 'The VMware View Connection Server (broker) requested the session to end.'
                        elif code == '304':
                                print 'PCoIP session terminated due to Power Sleep disconnect (not used for VDI).'
                        elif code == '305':
                                print 'PCoIP session terminated due to user pulling out the smart card used for user authentication.'
                        elif code == '306':
                                print 'PCoIP session terminated due to user taking action specified by OneSign to be a disconnect command (for example, double tapping the card).'
                        elif code == '400':
                                print 'Zero client and View 4.5 and earlier: PCoIP session terminated due to network issues on TCP/SSL connection (keepalive ping timeout).'
                        elif code == '401':
                                print 'PCoIP connection not established due to networking issues or failure to open drivers, such as video, audio, or USB.'
                        elif code == '402':
                                print 'PCoIP connection not established due to networking issues.'
                        elif code == '403':
                                print 'PCoIP session terminated due to various reasons. For example, network lost or client/server crash.'
                        elif code == '404':
                                print 'PCoIP connection not established due to inability to use the VMware video driver on the server.'
                        elif code == '405':
                                print 'PCoIP connection not established due to client and server not having a common encryption method enabled.'
                        elif code == '406':
                                print 'Zero Client and View 4.5 and earlier: PCoIP session terminated due to network issues on TCP/SSL connection. Zero client and View 4.6 (and later). This is normal operation since the TCP/SSL connection is terminated right after session negotiation.'
                        elif code == '407':
                                print 'PCoIP connection not established due to the View Security Server detecting that AES encryption is disabled on either the client and/or server.'
                        else:
                                print 'code not found in KB.'
                                return 0;


for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/users/home10/tshrestha/brb-view/logs/vdm-sdct-agent/pcoip-logs"):
        lineContainsServerFile = re.compile('.*server.*')
        for filename in files:
                if lineContainsServerFile.match(filename):
                        filename = os.path.join(root,filename)
                        with open(filename,'rb') as filehandle:
                                function_pcoip_packetloss(filehandle);
                                filehandle.seek(0)
                                function_pcoip_decrease(filehandle);
                                filehandle.seek(0)
                                function_disconnect_codes(filehandle);

#variable defined to check for certain pattern or word in the file
lineContains_os_name = re.compile('.*Operating System.*')
lineContains_host_name = re.compile('.*Machine name.*')
lineContains_installed_memory = re.compile('.*Total Physical Memory.*')
lineContains_Vcpu = re.compile('.*Processor.*')
lineContains_java_heap_key_string = re.compile('.*JvmOptions.*')
lineContains_java_heap_key = re.compile('.*TomcatService.*')
lineContains_network_adapter = re.compile('.*Adapter.*')
lineContains_firewall_status = re.compile('.*firewall.*')

#opening a file to write the output of the script
with open("/users/home10/tshrestha/brb-view/logs/vdm-sdct-agent/computer-config/view_outputfile",'w') as file_open:
        sys.stdout = file_open
        with open("/users/home10/tshrestha/brb-view/logs/vdm-sdct-agent/computer-config/dxdiag.txt", 'rb') as files:                                    #open the input file to read from it
                for filename in files:                                                          #loops to go through the file line by line
                        if lineContains_os_name.match(filename):                        #checks if the file has Operating System name
                                operating_system = filename.strip(' ')                  #format the output
print operating_system                                          #print the name of OS
                                if "Windows 7 Service Pack 1" in filename:              #checks if it is Service Pack 1 and print the required KB no.
                                        print "The ", operating_system ,"Please refer to the Microsoft Knowledge Base article 2550978"
                                else:
                                        print "The ",operating_system, "Please refer to the Microsoft Knowledge Base article 2344941\n"

                        if lineContains_host_name.match(filename):              #looks for the host name
                                host_name = filename.strip('')
                                print '\n'
                                print host_name

#opening the input file to get the name of network adapter
with open("/users/home10/tshrestha/brb-view/logs/vdm-sdct-agent/computer-config/ipconfig-all.txt", 'rb') as filename1:                          #open the input file to read from it
        for line1 in filename1:
                if lineContains_network_adapter.findall(line1):         #looks for network adaptor
                        network_adapter = line1.strip('')
                        print network_adapter

#opening the input file system-info to get the number of virtual cpu and installed physical memomry
with open("/users/home10/tshrestha/brb-view/logs/vdm-sdct-agent/computer-config/systeminfo.txt", 'rb') as filename2:                            #open the input file to read from it
        for line2 in filename2:
                if lineContains_Vcpu.findall(line2):                            #looks for number of Virtual CPU
                        no_vcpu = line2.strip('')
                        print no_vcpu
                if lineContains_installed_memory.findall(line2):        #looks for installed physical memory
                        installed_memory = line2.strip('')
                        print installed_memory

print '-----------------'
print 'JAVA HEAP KEY'
print '-----------------'
with open("/users/home10/tshrestha/brb-view/loginfo_outputfile", 'w') as outputfilename:
        sys.out = outputfilename
        with open("/users/home10/tshrestha/brb-view/logs/vdm-sdct-cs/vdm-config/vmware-reg.txt", 'rb') as filename3:                                    #open the input file to read from it
                for line3 in filename3:
                        if lineContains_java_heap_key_string.findall(line3):            #looks for Java Heap Keys
                                heap_key_string = line3.strip('')
                                print heap_key_string
                        if lineContains_java_heap_key.findall(line3):
                                java_heap_key = line3.strip('')
                                print java_heap_key


name = getpass.getuser()        #assigning a variable to the current user
msg = {}
msg["From"] = name + "@vmware.com"              #assigning a variable to the current user as a Sender
msg["To"] = name + "@vmware.com"                #assigning a variable to the current user as a Recei
msg["Subject"] = "LOG INFO"                             #assining a variable to the subject field

#using bash script in python; sendmail; subject to and from and the outputfile
os.system("/usr/bin/mail -s " + msg["Subject"] + " " + msg["To"] +" < outputfilename")
```

Comment: WOAH thats a lot of code. Please read [minimal](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Double-check for whitespaces near the line 139 (`print network_adapter`).

Comment: This happens if sys.stdout is not open..., so, did anything print? How was this thing called?

Comment: sorry new bie thought whole code would help.... check the whitespaces did not help @tdelaney it print the code and the print after but when I goes does the same error keeps coming up

Answer (score 0):

You assign sys.stdout to file_open and file_open closes at the end of the with statement. *print* sends its output to sys.stdout, but its now the closed filed. If you want to write to files, just stick with file_open.write("the string") and don't redirect stdout.

Looking at the code, I think that the 'with' blocks for *ipconfig-all.txt* and *systeminfo.txt* should be indented to that they are contained within the 'with' block for the outputfile.

Comment: I tried to indent the blocks for ipconfig-all.txt and systeminfo.txt and then same error moves down to 151 and then i removed the std.out from there and indented that too..but then it does not print anything from java heap key

Comment: _print_ writes to sys.stdout, not sys.out. Are you expecting some print statements to go to a file and some to the screen?

Comment: Yes, I am trying sys.stdout to write some to file and print some to screen. I tried putting everything in function but still getting error. thank you for your help

Comment: if I try to print everything to the file it seem to work, trying to fix the email thing, was trying to create function to find match(reuse code). Can you suggest me how to make the code better and what to do if I want some to print in the screen and some to file? thank you